# Excel VBA, Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I'm pretty new to VBA and cannot get a `loop` work.

Column J contains certain **ID numbers**. For each **ID number** I have several rows displayed in my database. I sorted my database on column J (ascending order). 
I would like to filter for all the values in columns J and copy all the rows for each **ID number** into a new sheet what I want to rename as the **ID number**.
Here is the macro but the `loop` doesn't work (`Run-time error 13, Type mismatch, error in the following code row: For i = 45 To LastEmpNo`)

Any help would be welcomed. Thanks

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim MyDataFirstCell
Dim MyDataLastCell
Dim EmpNoStart
Dim EmpNoFinish
Dim i As Integer

Range("A1").Select
MyDataFirstCell = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
MyDataLastCell = ActiveCell.Address 

Range("J2").Select
EmpNoStart = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
EmpNoFinish = ActiveCell.Address

Range(EmpNoStart & ":" & EmpNoFinish).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Columns _
    ("K:K"), Unique:=True

Dim FirstEmpNo
Dim LastEmpNo

Range("K2").Select
FirstEmpNo = ActiveCell.Address
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
LastEmpNo = ActiveCell.Address

For i = FirstEmpNo To LastEmpNo

    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range(MyDataFirstCell & ":" & MyDataLastCell).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=i
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Range("C1").Activate
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = i

Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot iterate from one string value to another. The "For" loop is expecting two numeric values.

```
?activecell.Address
$C$9
?activecell.Row
 9
```

Therefore:

```
FirstEmpNo = ActiveCell.Row
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
LastEmpNo = ActiveCell.Row
```